# How to correctly configure apache for reverse proxy serve django app

Tags: django, apache, reverse-proxy

Hi I've been trying to correctly configure apache as reverse proxy for my django application.
When served from port :4300 it goes all fine, but when I tried to use reverse-proxy all goes wrong.

When I try to acces when logged in

> 192.168.100.201/fact

I get the expected functionality, but when I press anything to admin app of django i get

> 192.168.100.201/admin

when I should get

> 192.168.100.201/fact/admin

Even if I write it in the browser I'm still redirected to 192.168.100.201/admin

I kwon that maybe is a dub question but it is something that I couldnt realize.

**settings.py**

"""

```
Django settings for SEMFAC project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.13.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'wkf8aie3kc6@xb0-_y%rwmp*tq)hqv7t+d0l6a9wop0l$1m336'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.100.205','192.168.100.203','192.168.100.201']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'fact.apps.FactConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'SEMFAC.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'SEMFAC.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en-US', _('English')),
    ('es-MX', _('Espanol')),
)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-MX'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
```

In the urls.py file this is the configuration

```
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^',include('fact.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

In my django.conf file the configuration is the following

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.100.205:4300>
Alias /static /opt/SEMFAC/fact/static
<Directory /opt/SEMFAC/fact/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /opt/SEMFAC/SEMFAC>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>



WSGIDaemonProcess SEMFAC python-path=/opt/SEMFAC:/opt/SEMFAC/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup SEMFAC
WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/SEMFAC/SEMFAC/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

And the configuration within apache i have

```
<Location /fact>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass http://192.168.100.205:4300
  ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.100.205:4300
</Location>
```

Comment: This is a bit strange. Why are you using Apache both to serve your site (via mod_wsgi) *and* as a reverse proxy? What is the proxy adding in this situation?

Comment: Thank you for your interest, the intention for this is to get served several backend application trough port :80, within a reverse proxy front

Comment: But, again, Apache can do that directly via multiple VirtualHosts.

Comment: Ok got it, thanks @DanielRoseman I will give it a try.

Comment: Ok, I have now the desired functionality, information above was just for my development enviroment, so in a production enviroment the proxy part will mask my back-end servers, adding an additional protection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is what did the trick

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.100.205:4300>
Alias /fact/static /opt/SEMFAC/fact/static
<Directory /opt/SEMFAC/fact/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /opt/SEMFAC/SEMFAC>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>


WSGIDaemonProcess SEMFAC python-path=/opt/SEMFAC:/opt/SEMFAC/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup SEMFAC
WSGIScriptAlias /fact /opt/SEMFAC/SEMFAC/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /fact http://192.168.100.205:4300/fact
    ProxyPassReverse /fact http://192.168.100.205:4300/fact

    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```